# I got blurry text if use Bootstrap 4 carousel on my website

Tags: carousel, z-index, bootstrap-4

I'm developing a website where I have to put a bootstrap carousel and different texts over this carousel (absolute element).

Once I put the carousel on the website, all the texts become blurry and difficult to read.

I've read the could a problem between z-index of the text and z-index of the carousel but I'm not getting how I can solve it because I have to keep this text over the carousel.

Here the image of what I'm developing:

[image]

Here my code:

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 top-header-container">
            <ul>
                <li>UK 33333</li>
                <li>IRELAND 333333</li>
                <li>CANADA 333333</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 background-img-slide" style="z-index: -10px;">

            <div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                <!-- Indicators -->
                <ul class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ul>

                <!-- The slideshow -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/assets/img/image-home-main.jpg" alt="" width="100%" height="800">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/assets/img/image-home-main.jpg" alt="" width="100%" height="800">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/assets/img/image-home-main.jpg" alt="" width="100%" height="800">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Left and right controls -->
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
                </a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="logo-wrap">
        <div class="logo-container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><img class="logo-img" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/assets/img/deane-logo.png"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <nav class="main_menu_container">
        <ul class="main_menu_class">
            <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Policies</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="slide-title-blue-wrap">
        <div class="slide-title-blue-container">
            <span class="slide-title-blue">tefdjsafkljdasfkljkjfdlskalòs</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide-title-red-wrap">
        <div class="slide-title-red-container">
            <span class="slide-title-red">tefdjsafkljdasfkljkjfdlskalòs</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide-title-green-wrap">
        <div class="slide-title-green-container">
            <span class="slide-title">tefdjsafkljdasfkljkjfdlskalòs</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.top-header-container {
    text-align: right;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.top-header-container > ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.top-header-container > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.main_menu_container {
    text-align: right;
    position: absolute;
    width: 58%;
    right: -110px;
    top: 55px;
}

.main_menu_container > ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding-right: 150px;
    background: #76bd21;
    transform: skewX(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: skewX(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-45deg);
}

.main_menu_container > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 15px;
    transform: skewX(45deg);
    -ms-transform: skewX(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewX(45deg);
}

.main_menu_container > ul > li > a {
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.main_menu_container > ul > li > a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.logo-wrap {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -835px;
    margin-left: -35px;
}

.logo-container {
    position: absolute;
    left: -450px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.82);
    height: 800px;
    width: 50%;
    transform: skewX(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: skewX(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-45deg);
}

.navbar-brand {
    transform: skewX(45deg);
    -ms-transform: skewX(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewX(45deg);
}

.logo-img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 110px;
    top: 40px;
}


.background-img-slide {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -100px;
    background-image: url(assets/img/image-home-main.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 850px;
}

.slide-title-blue-wrap {
    position: relative;
}

.slide-title-blue-container {
    position: absolute;
    left: -689px;
    top: -7px;
    background: rgba(5, 34, 162, 0.85);
    height: 700px;
    width: 60%;
    transform: skewX(45deg);
    -ms-transform: skewX(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewX(45deg);
    z-index: 15;
}

.slide-title-blue {
    position: absolute;
    top: 70%;
    left: 65%;
    transform: skewX(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: skewX(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-45deg);
    color: #fff;
}

.slide-title-green-wrap {
    position: relative;
}

.slide-title-green-container {
    position: absolute;
    left: -881px;
    top: 835px;
    background: rgba(118, 189, 33, 0.85);
    height: 800px;
    width: 60%;
    transform: skewX(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: skewX(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-45deg);
    z-index: 10;
}

.slide-title-red-wrap {
    position: relative;
}

.slide-title-red-container {
    position: absolute;
    left: -410px;
    top: 693px;
    background: rgba(5, 34, 162, 0.85);
    height: 142px;
    width: 60%;
    transform: skewX(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: skewX(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-45deg);
    z-index: 15;
}

.slide-title-red {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: skewX(45deg);
    -ms-transform: skewX(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewX(45deg);
    color: #fff;
}
```

Blurry text (with carousel)

[image]

Clear text (without carousel)

[image]

Here link of my test website:

http://www.matrix-test.com/roofing/

Any Idea to solve this problem?

Comment: Please include your code.

Comment: Sorry, just added the code

Comment: At least you should change `col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12` to just `col-12`. It applies for all sizes.

Comment: The red text looks more blurry than the white text... and to be honest, the white text doesn't even look blurry. Please provide an image to a raw/uncompressed image so that we can see in HD quality.

Comment: Sorry, I added the red text before uploading the image to highlight the blurry text and make it more understandable. I just uploaded two new pictures and the link of my test website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to resolve this issue in Bootstrap 4 by setting the `backface-visibility` attribute of the `carousel-item` to unset.

Here's the code.

```
.carousel-item {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: unset!important;
    backface-visibility: unset!important;
}
```

Comment: Hi Tidy, everything works perfectly in Chrome and Safari but I'm having some issue with Firefox. The slide on Firefox doesn't work properly anymore I get a graphics error when the slide changes